# Retorno de funções em C

Tags: c, funções

Uma coisa muito comum e pratico em linguagens interpretadas é o retorno de funções a partir de outra função.

Mas em linguagens compiladas assim como **C**, é possível fazer o retorno de uma função?

Comment: Todas as linguagens de programação ou pelo menos a maior parte tem retorno de valores, no caso do C tem retorno para todos os tipos primitivos e structs com exceção do void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível retornar funções em C igual como em linguagens interpretadas.

Em *Lua*, pode-se declarar a função que deseja retornar, já no retorno da função. Ex:

```
function return_func()
    return function(x,y) print(x+y) end
end
```

Mas o compilador do C, não possui recurso para fazer esse tipo de retorno, então deve criar um ponteiro para a função.

```
void *fcn_res(){
    int sum(int x, int y){ // função que irá ser retornada
        return x+y;
    }

    void *(*res)(); // declaração genérica do ponteiro da função
    res = (void *(*)())sum;

    return (void*) res;
}

int main(){
    int (*fcn)(int, int) = fcn_res(); // atribui sum em fcn

    printf("%d\n", fcn(13,11));
    return 0;
}
```